# Bad Requests in Token Service API when using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Recently I've noticed that the Firebase database do not properly sync local changes with the remote database in our Android application for some of our users. Monitoring the `.info/connected` path indicates that a connection is never properly established for these users, and listening for authentication state via `FirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener` returns a non-null current user.

I've debugged the issue with `FirebaseDatabase.setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` and these messages seems to be repeated every second or so while the app is active:

```
D PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
W BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
D PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: An internal error has occurred. [ TOKEN_EXPIRED ]
D PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 767ms
```

Looking inside the Google API console, I can see lots of `400 Bad Request` errors for the "Token Service API" for the credential used by the Android app. The API method is `google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken`. This is not called by our app manually - I believe it is used internally by Firebase Auth to keep tokens up to date.

It seems to me that the FirebaseAuth library is doing bad requests when trying to refresh an expired authentication token. Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I'm having a hard time finding the root cause of this issue since it is not immediately reproducible (only happens for some users, both using Google and email providers). I'm not sure if it's possible to dig through the Token Service API logs in some way to get more detailed messages? The other clients using Firebase authentication (iOS and Web) are working without any issues.

Comment: I´m experiencing the exactly same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Itapox Sorry for the delayed response. I've not yet found a solution, but I'm not receiving the same amount of errors as before. According to the graph, it started getting better on April 5. Do you see the same behaviour?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error; solved it by:

1. Going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials,
2. Clicking on the API key
3. Enabling the "Token Service API", along with "Identity Toolkit API"

Comment: I'm chasing this issue for a week now. This was the problem. Thanks!